# Applying list of slices representing 2D patches to 3D numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I have a numpy array representing an image (but for now assume the image only has a single channel).

```
i = np.arange(5*5*1).reshape((5, 5))
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

I also have a rather large list of pre-computed slices of this array in the format `[start_axis_0, end_axis_0, start_axis_1, end_axis_1]` (for now just assume I have two)

```
p = [[0, 2, 0, 2], [0, 2, 1, 3]]
```

This represents the two corresponding patches from `i`

```
i[0:2, 0:2]
array([[0, 1],
       [5, 6]])
i[0:2, 1:3]
array([[1, 2],
       [6, 7]])
```

To calculate these patches I am currently iterating over `p` and "applying" the slices.

```
for pp in p:
    print(i[pp[0]:pp[1], pp[2]:pp[3]])
[[0 1]
 [5 6]]
[[1 2]
 [6 7]]
```

I know that there is some way that I can "directly apply" all of the slices at once using something like `i[(Ellipsis, *p)]` but I don't think my `p` definition is correct.

**How can I get the slices defined in `p` from `i` in the current data structure of `p`?** The is where `p` is represented as `[start_axis_0, end_axis_0, start_axis_1, end_axis_1]`. *Specifically,* in the case that `i` has an actual third dimension, i.e. `i.shape = (5, 5, 3)`.

---

EDIT: The result I would like is

```
np.array([[[0,1],[5,6]],[[1,2],[6,7]]])
```

Also, all slices in `p` are guaranteed to be the same shape. So the result will not be a jagged array.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "get the slices"? Do you want a list such that each element of the list is one of these slices?

Comment: @BenGrossmann by "get the slices" I mean get the subset of `i` that represents the slice in `p`. So yes, essentially a `list` or `array`. In the example in the post I'd want the result `r = np.array([[[0,1],[5,6]], [[1,2],[6,7]]])`

Answer (score 2):

If all slices have a fixed shape you can try this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(5*5*1).reshape((5, 5))
p = [[0, 2, 0, 2], [0, 2, 1, 3]]
slice_shape = (2, 2)

# since the slice shape is fixed, only the coordinates of
# the upper left corner of each slice are needed 
idx = tuple(zip(*[(t[0], t[2]) for t in p]))

result = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(a, slice_shape)[idx]
print(result)
```

It gives:

```
[[[0 1]
  [5 6]]

 [[1 2]
  [6 7]]]
```